# Can not load personal font using XLoadFont

Tags: c, fonts, x11

Hi I am new to X11 and I'm trying to load a font from a directory using XLoadFont and then printing some text with XDrawText but for some reason, I can't  load the font (.ttf format) where I load the font:

```
static void setFont(
    Object *_this,
    const char *path)
{
    mc_textPr *this = _this;
    Display *display = getDisplay();
    Font tmp = XLoadFont(display, path);

    if (!tmp) {
        raise("Invalid path to font\n");
        return;
    }
    unloadFont(this->text.font, display);
    this->text.font = tmp;
}
```

Before you, tell me that X11 is hard and should use something else it is for a school project which requires the use of X11.

I also know about this to resources

http://xopendisplay.hilltopia.ca/2009/Feb/Xlib-tutorial-part-4----Text.html

https://tronche.com/gui/x/

but I can't find why it freaks out.

here is the actual Error :

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  45 (X_OpenFont)
  Serial number of failed request:  17
  Current serial number in output stream:  27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XLoadFont()` can only load X11 bitmap fonts which are already available to the X server. It cannot load TTF font files, and it cannot load fonts from files you specify.

To find the names of fonts that are available on your system, run `xfontsel`.

Virtually all modern software uses external libraries, like Cairo, to draw text. X11 fonts are only used by a few very old applications, like xterm.

Comment: Thank you. I gess gonna use pixmap font then

Comment: Yes, @julia / @user149341, and if you can give us some hints about where to get them and how to load them (`/usr/share/fonts/misc/`?) that would be nice. https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libx11-doc/XLoadFont.3.en.html. For ArchLinux for instance I found `pacman` package: `extra/terminus-font`, but it's not enough / not the right one.

Comment: Or maybe something needs to be run to recognise the fonts. I find `fc-list` lists `/usr/share/fonts/misc/10x20.pcf.gz: Misc Fixed:style=Regular` which looks like it should be available for call `gcv.font = XLoadFont(display, "10x20");` but I still get `BadName` (`45 (X_OpenFont)`).